# Emberjs acceptance testing - should I mock services?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

For ember acceptance tests is it best practice to mock services? This seems strange to me as I would expect an acceptance test not to have to mock anything as it's testing an entire system. Also, some features may call several different services.

Can someone help me out with the best approach? Trying to test my application but receive errors when the service is called.

Comment: What do you mean by "best?"

Comment: Hi Robert. Perhaps standard practice would have been a better term. Like I said it seems strange to have to mock anything for an acceptance test.

Comment: Well, yes.  By definition, an acceptance test would not include mocks, because you would be testing the *actual* system, not a system of fake objects.

Comment: Yes, that would be my understanding of an acceptance tests too. However my tests fail when I interact with something that causes a service to be called, i.e clicking a button. From digging around it seems people(some at least) do mock services in acceptance tests, hence my question.

Comment: Well, what problem are you trying to solve then?  Your test isn't failing because it's non-standard, or because you misunderstand the purpose of mocks; it's failing because it's a broken test.

Comment: Problems im trying to solve is how to have

Comment: It appears that the last comment you posted got truncated.

Comment: Sorry, must not have saved it correctly. I guess my question is, what do I need to do to get my test working? How does the service become available for the acceptance test to use? This article:(https://www.codementor.io/ember-js/tutorial/testing-emberjs-with-ember-cli) mentions the dependency injection system, is that how to do it? Can't seem to find much examples of acceptance tests and services so unsure as to how to proceed.

Comment: I suggest you post the code of your test to Stack Overflow and see if they can help you troubleshoot it.